# Your Second iOS App - Enable Persistent Master List

Tags: objective-c, ios

So i'm following the ios tutorial here

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SecondiOSAppTutorial/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011318-CH1-SW1

The data for the tableview is a custom class containing just strings and dates.

Here is what it looks like

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SecondiOSAppTutorial/DesigningDataModel/DesigningDataModel.html

Can anyone suggest how to save this to data between launches of the app?

Comment: Take a look at NSCoding.

Comment: I did consider NSCoding but as the custom class only contains strings and dates, isnt this overkill?

Comment: No. I would say not. It's quite easy to use, and for such simple data seems to be the best choice. You could also practice Core Data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `NSCoding` to store such simple data. You could probably even use `NSUserDefaults` but I wouldn't recommend it. Core Data is really the way to go unless you know you'll never need anything slightly more complex.

Check out [this guide](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1914/how-to-save-your-app-data-with-nscoding-and-nsfilemanager) on how to persist simple data using `NSCoding` from [www.raywenderlich.com](http://www.raywenderlich.com) - a really good tutorial site for people beginning iOS development.

Comment: An alternative would be to use the writeTo methods on NSDictionary/NSArray - supports various formats.  NSCoding/CoreData are the more generally useful techniques, however.

Answer (score 1):

What about making the app Document based .. i.e. using [UIDocument](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDocument_Class/UIDocument/UIDocument.html)?

Answer (score 0):

You *could* use `NSCoding` or `NSUserDefaults`.

But for any real application that has a lot more than sample data you'll be looking at something like [Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html) eventually.

From your comments I see that you think it's overkill for just a couple of fields. However, this is an ideal time to learn about and practice setting up a Core Data model and connecting it to a table view with a Fetched results controller.